# Solving the recurrence relation $T(n)=3T\Big(\frac{n}{2}\Big)+n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, recurrence-relations

> Use the expand, guess and verify approach to solve the following recurrence relation
> $$\cases{T(1) = 1\\T(n) = 3T\Big(\frac{n}{2}\Big)+n & for $n > 1$}$$

I think it's defined for $n=2^m$, $m>1$, so here's my attempt: $$T(n)=3T\Big(\frac{n}{2}\Big)+n=T(n)=3^2T\Big(\frac{n}{2^2}\Big)+\frac{3}{2}+n=3^3T\Big(\frac{n}{2^3}\Big)+\frac{3^2}{2^2}n+\frac{3}{2}n+n$$

I guess that after $k$ steps, we get $$T(n)=3^kT\Big(\frac{n}{2^k}\Big)+n\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \Big(\frac{3}{2}\Big)^i$$

Setting $k=\log n$, $$T(n)=3^{\log n}+n\sum_{i=0}^{\log (n)-1} \Big(\frac{3}{2}\Big)^i$$

I'm having a hard time proving the previous formula by induction. I tried this:

Base case: $$T(1)=3^{0}+1\sum_{i=0}^{0-1} \Big(\frac{3}{2}\Big)^i =(?) 1$$

Is that summation equal to zero? Those indices got me wondering. Also, assuming everything is correct so far, I got stuck when trying to write down the induction step.

Inductive step: If $T(k)$ is true, then $T(2k)$ must be true too. So, $$T(2k)=3T(k)+2k$$ $$T(2k)=3^{\log 2k}+3k\sum_{i=0}^{\log (k)-1} \Big(\frac{3}{2}\Big)^i + 2k$$ The last step doesn't seem to be correct. Any help, please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: $T(3)$ can be anything.

Comment: With the $T(n) = 3T\Big(\frac{n}{2}\Big)+n$ part for $n \gt 1$, if $n$ is odd, how is the $T$ function defined for non-integral values (e.g., with $n =3 $, for $\frac{3}{2}$)?

Comment: I think it's defined for $n=2^m$, $m \geq 1$.

Comment: @MauricioMendes Thanks for your prompt response (although you wrote "think", so it seems you're not sure, but that seems like a reasonable assumption, although I believe another reasonable possibility is there's something like a floor function missing instead). Please add this to your question text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So indeed,
$$
\begin{split}
T(n)
 &= 3T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right) + n \\
 &= 3 \left[3T\left(\frac{n}{4}\right) + \frac{n}{2}\right] + n\\
 &= 3^2 T\left(\frac{n}{2^2}\right) + \frac{3n}{2} + n\\
 &= 3^3 T\left(\frac{n}{2^3}\right) + \frac{3^2}{2^2} n + \frac{3n}{2} + n\\
 &= \ldots \\
 &= 3^k T\left(\frac{n}{2^k}\right) + n \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \left(\frac32\right)^i\\
 &= 3^k T\left(\frac{n}{2^k}\right) + n \frac{(3/2)^k - 1}{3/2-1}\\
 &= 3^k T\left(\frac{n}{2^k}\right) + 2n \left[\left(\frac32\right)^k - 1\right]\\
 &= 3^k \left[T\left(\frac{n}{2^k}\right) + \frac{2n}{2^k} \right] - 2n\\
\end{split}
$$
Finally, substituting $k= \log_2 n = \lg n \iff n = 2^k$, we get
$$
T(n)
 = 3^{\lg n} \left[T(1)+2\right]-2n
 = 3 \cdot 3^{\lg n}-2n
 = 3^{\lg (2n)}-2n.
$$

---

For the inductive step, note $\lg(2n) = \lg 2 + \lg n = 1 + \lg n$, so you assume $T(n) = 3^{\lg (2n)}-2n$ and prove that $T(2n) = 3^{\lg (4n)} - (4n)$.

Comment: I believe that the upper limit of the sum should be $k - 1$, not $k$ (though it doesn't make much of a difference).

Comment: @an4s +1, fixed, please check again thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$\begin{align}T(n) &= 3T\left(\dfrac n2\right) + n\tag{1} \\ T(n) &= 3^{\log n} + n\sum_{i=0}^{\log (n)-1} \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^i\tag{2}\end{align}$$

If you set $n = 1$ in as your base case, then you end up with $T\left(\dfrac 12\right)$ in $(1)$ which does not mean anything. Instead, set $n = 2$ as your base case. Then, $(1)$ becomes $$T(2) = 3\times T(1) + 2 = 3\times 1 + 2 = 5$$ and $(2)$ becomes $$T(2) = 3^{\log 2} + 2\times\left(\dfrac 32\right)^0 = 3^1+2\times1 = 5$$ and you can see that $(1)\equiv(2)$. The base case, therefore, holds.

Answer (score 0):

As

$$
T\left(2^{\log_2 n}\right) = 3T\left(2^{\log_2 \frac n2}\right)+n
$$

making $\mathcal{T}(\cdot) = T\left(2^{(\cdot)}\right)$ and $z = \log_2 n$ we follow with

$$
\mathcal{T}(z) = 3\mathcal{T}(z-1) + 2^z
$$

with solution

$$
\mathcal{T}(z) = 3^{z-1}c_0+2(3^z-2^z)
$$

and going backwards with $z=\log_2 n$ we obtain

$$
T(n) = 3^{\log_2 n-1}c_0 +2(n-3^{\log_2 n})
$$

and obeying the initial conditions

$$
T(n) = 3^{\log_2(2n)}-2n
$$

Comment: Why the down vote?